WSNAT_CAT:1175: WARN: Disconnecting listener connection to workstation, request timed out
We have a Tuxedo 10.3 (32 bit) and when launching the client app initially it is working good, but in 2 days it started showing slowness in app launching and taking time to load. But eventually connects with delay.
Also now we are seeing this issue in hourly basis and the Tuxedo boot seems to be required for more reequently.
The error shown in serverside is :
WSNAT_CAT:1175: WARN: Disconnecting listener connection to workstation, request timed out

From the desktop client end:
05-13-2024: Tuxedo Version 10.3.0.0 with VS2005, 32-bit
LIBWSC_CAT:1037: ERROR: Network message receive failure
LIBWSC_CAT:1059: ERROR: WSL returns error on connection request
LIBWSC_CAT:1055: ERROR: Unable to establish WSL connection
LIBWSC_CAT:1027: ERROR: Unable to connect to WSH
LIBWSC_CAT:1020: ERROR: Unable to obtain authentication level

We have the tuxedo installed in AWS Ec2 instance and the traffic routed via NLB.
The telnet to the both WSL and WSH is perfect and connected. But only problem is the application not able to launch or slowness after a period of time and as a workarround this gets solved after every reboot of the application using tmshutdown/tmboot.
Which might be going wrong here, we have the 15 ports in WSH and 1 in WSL active. Kindly advise.

Sounds like your problem is in using a tool rather than writing the tool. For some tools, the ones used to write programs, we can help you here, but other tools are off topic. Maybe this is a job for Server Fault, but I'm not familiar enough with the site to be comfortable recommending it.

@user4581301, is there way to find or set the log level of the ULOG of tuxedo to ERROR and see more data related to this disconnect/timed out issue ?

Migrate to open-source Enduro/X. Use endurox-connect package which would allow you to expose your XATMI services as https rest services for your desktop app. Global transaction management over the rest services are supported too.
